# LinkButton not firing ASP.NET validators

Tags: asp.net, validation

I have a form that currently uses an  control to submit a form. Everything works perfectly. So now the new requirement is for the "submit' button to be a link. Changing it to a LinkButton control, without changing a SINGLE other thing, breaks the validation.

There is a bit too much code to post in a SO question and I know there's a bit of a lack of detail here, but is there any reason why a LinkButton wouldn't fire ASP.NET validation the same way a Button control would? In theory, they should both operate exactly the same, no?

The current submit button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" TabIndex="9" Text="Send" ValidationGroup="Forward" runat="server" />
```

The new submit button:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit" TabIndex="9" Text="Send" ValidationGroup="Forward" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The Link button should fires the validation the same way a normal button does, my concerns in your case would be the following:

1. make sure these is nothing in the server side code stopping this.
2. make sure in the javascript code there is nothing stopping the "

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET controls that fire validation has a property called [CauseValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.causesvalidation.aspx)

Be sure all controls should fire validation, has this property set to `True`

Answer (score 0):

Add attribute `CauseValidation="True"` to your control but if you want to fire this at particular line at code behind you can use validate the form by the following code:

```
FormID.Validate();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but it has never answered. Did your validator have a "controlTovalidate"? Currently it would appear as if the validator was not firing but in reality it is. It just does not have anything that it is 'watching'. Hope if anyone reaches this thread that this helps even if it is just a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to determine the cause of this issue but was able to solve it:

I set the CausesValidation="false" and added at the top of the onclick event this.Validate(linkButton.ValidationGroup) this allows the event to get to the code behind and validation to occur.